# MySQL: Select Data from multiple Columns

Tags: mysql

Could someone help me combine the count values together?

```
 Select count(*) from swtickets
 inner join swdepartments on swtickets.departmentid = swdepartments.departmentid
 inner join swticketstatus on swtickets.ticketstatusid = swticketstatus.ticketstatusid
 inner join swticketpriorities on swtickets.priorityid = swticketpriorities.priorityid
 where
 swdepartments.title = "XXX" and
 swticketstatus.title = "Open"
```

The above outputs a value which works, however we wish to group a few more into the output value; could you assist us?

```
 swticketstatus.title = "Open"
 swticketstatus.title = "Driving Job"
 swticketstatus.title = "Project Work"
 swticketstatus.title = "Out of Hours"
```

Comment: I hope you want to count total rows which contain above mentioned Title's

Comment: Oh! Please EDIT you question & write this comment there!

Comment: AK47, could you view the above and tell us how to add the totals from the other statues?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want this,

```
Select count(*) from swtickets
 inner join swdepartments on swtickets.departmentid = swdepartments.departmentid
 inner join swticketstatus on swtickets.ticketstatusid = swticketstatus.ticketstatusid
 inner join swticketpriorities on swtickets.priorityid = swticketpriorities.priorityid
 where
 swdepartments.title = "XXX" and
 (
    swticketstatus.title = "Open"
    OR
    swticketstatus.title = "Driving Job"
    OR
    swticketstatus.title = "Project Work"
    OR
    swticketstatus.title = "Out of Hours"
 )
```

If not `OR` you can use `IN`

```
Select count(*) from swtickets
 inner join swdepartments on swtickets.departmentid = swdepartments.departmentid
 inner join swticketstatus on swtickets.ticketstatusid = swticketstatus.ticketstatusid
 inner join swticketpriorities on swtickets.priorityid = swticketpriorities.priorityid
 where
 swdepartments.title = "XXX" 
 and swticketstatus.title IN("Open","Driving Job","Project Work","Out of Hours")
```